# Unable to generate JMeter HTML reports for distributed load tests

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

Context: I am trying to generate HTML report for a JMeter test on a distributed load system with 1:1 master slave ratio, with the following command:
sh jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l testresult.jtl -R x.x.x.x -e -o /home/ubuntu/reports

I get the following error:

```
Configuring remote engine: x.x.x.x
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [x.x.x.x] @ Wed Aug 18 14:24                                                                                                       :47 UTC 2021 (1629296687532)
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Remote engines have been started:[]
The following remote engines have not started:[x.x.x.x]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
```

The run is successful when run locally but not when triggered through the master onto the slave.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that JMeter master cannot start the test on the slave, either your configuration is wrong or there is something preventing bidirectional connectivity between the master and the slave ([firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))?)

It's hard to say what's wrong without knowing network interfaces information of the master and the slave and the configuration you applied to connect them to each other so I can only provide some links to useful materials:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, thanks a lot for your reply. I am actually able to run remote tests successfully when i don't have the html report command (-e -o) and the settings haven't been tampered with for a long time.